# XSLT - Transform the value of an attribute to a tagname

Tags: xslt

I have been looking for a while and I do not understand how I can do something like this:

From

`<computer type="laptop">
    ....
</computer>`

To

```
<laptop>
....
```

In fact as you can see I want to transform the **value** of an attribute to a tagname, I do not even know if it is possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use the `xsl:element` element.  With this, you can create an element with any name you choose.
e.g.

```
<xsl:element name="{@type}">
...
</xsl:element>
```